# yahoo finance data javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, drupal-7, yahoo-finance

1. I am currently holding a Drupal 7 site.
2. I would like to build a block with yahoo fiance api data on my
   sidebar, like:

   ```
   Nasdaq 2,951.23    16.18   +0.55%
   Dow    12,871.39   -8.70   -0.07%
   ```
3. I would like to do it using javascript, because in Drupal, I
   could make the js code directly imbedded in my inline content, which
   is easier than doing with php codes.

And the data I got from yahoo fiance is in .csv format, I need to parse it remotely from yahoo finance with the query looks like: http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=^IXIC,^GSPC,^FTSE,^GDAXI,^FCHI,^N225,^HSI,^STI,^BSESN,^NSEI&f=sl1c1&e=.csv

Ok, guys, help me out of this please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you will not be able to download a csv file from an external domain (yahoo.com) and show it to your users using JavaScript alone. There are cross domain restrictions preventing that.

You can however use a JSON version for finance data, like this with jQuery:

See this example on jsfiddle.net: http://jsfiddle.net/grimreaper01/jVWwu/

Comment: Hi darkAsPitch, thanks for your fast response, really appreciate. But I think what I do is quite simple, and somehow, I've already done it once using java and jsp in one of my school project. But now, I cannot call .java file in Drupal, as far as I'm concerned, so I have to migrate to the scripting language like js, and that's where I am stucked.  Besides, I've actually visited the link you provided, but it doesn't work for me. I put the codes in a <script> tags in a html file, did I do it the right way?

Comment: @darkAsPitch, isn't the Google Finance API been deprecated?